# How to delete row from Custom Class after a day of createdAt by using CloudCode

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform

I'm working on private chat application and I wanna delete my messages after a day of their createdAt field I looked around and couldn't find any helpful examples about calling cloud code after period

Can someone help me about methodology ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteMessages", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var ts = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var tsYesterday = ts - (24 * 3600);
    var dateYesterday = new Date(tsYesterday*1000);

    var query = new Parse.Query("Your Object Class");

    query.lessThan("createdAt", dateYesterday);

    query.find({
        success: function(result) {
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                result[i].destroy({
                    success: function(object) {
                        status.success("Delete job completed");
                        alert('Delete Successful');
                    },
                    error: function(object, error) {
                        status.error("Delete error :" + error);
                        alert('Delete failed');
                    }
                });
            }
            status.success("Delete job completed");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Error in delete query error: " + error);
            alert('Error in delete query');
        }
    });
});
```

after upload this code to your Parse Cloud code with using parse console which you can get information from [here](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started-installing) you just need to add your job into scheduled jobs tab and set your repeat.

Hope it'll help to u.
And thanks to you @Handsomeguy for idea

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of a task for background jobs. You create a background job to run at certain intervals that queries the message table for records that are older than 24 hours, and deletes those.

Learn more about background jobs on parse here: http://blog.parse.com/2013/09/04/introducing-background-jobs/